# Python threading only 1 process is started

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I know that there is a bunch of information on this, however I could not understand how to make it work.

I have two functions with "While True" loops, which I want to run in parallel (one of them is a PySimpleGui main function) the other checks the time and does something if the time has been reached.

```
def PSG_main_function():
    while True:
        do something

def clock_function():
    while True:
        do something
```

I tried to use the threading library to run both in parallel like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=PSG_main_function(), args=(1,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=clock_function(), args=(1,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

t1 is started but t2 in not.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=PSG_main_function, args=(1,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=clock_function, args=(1,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=PSG_main_function(), args=(1,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=clock_function(), args=(1,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

This here is wrong, when setting the target, you dont want to pass the result of the target function, but the function itself, so remove the parenthesis after the function name.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a function name to option `target` of method `threading.Thread`, not the result of that function.

Following code demo the way how to use the `threading.Thread`.

```py
import time
import datetime
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def job(window):
    global running
    while running:
        window.write_event_value('Event', datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        time.sleep(0.1)

layout = [
    [sg.Button('Start'), sg.Button('Stop')],
    [sg.Text("Time", size=0, expand_x=True, justification='center', key='Time')],
]
window = sg.Window('Threading', layout)
running, old = False, None

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        running = False
        time.sleep(0.1)
        break

    elif event == 'Start' and not running:
        running = True
        window['Start'].update(disabled=True)
        threading.Thread(target=job, args=(window, ), daemon=True).start()

    elif event == 'Stop':
        running = False
        window['Start'].update(disabled=False)

    elif event == 'Event':
        now = values[event]
        if now != old:
            window['Time'].update(now)
            old = now

window.close()
```

Comment: I like to use the "lambda" trick so that the `args` parm isn't needed and it looks like a function call.  `target=lambda: job(window)` is how I specify threads.  The PSG Demo Programs and docs use this convention.  I dunno if there are serious drawbacks.  I haven't had trouble so far.  There are also threading calls built-into PySimpleGUI now. This cookbook entry explains: https://pysimplegui.trinket.io/demo-programs#/multi-threaded/multi-threaded-download-2022-design-pattern